# Does O_SYNC mean atomic operation?

Tags: file, unix, atomic

Is an I/O function using `O_SYNC` atomic? For example:

```
fd = open("user.data", O_RDONLY | O_SYNC);
pread(fd, &buf, sizeof(User), 100*sizeof(User));
```

In this case, is the `pread` atomic? Note: there is no any file lock lick `flock` or `fcntl`.

Answer (score 0):

Atomic with respect to what?

### With respect to buf?

Then no, most likely data will be copied to your program in a serial fashion by the operating system. Other threads may or may not see chunks of the updates at a time. If you to protect accesses to buf, you'll want to use a semaphore or mutex to serialize access to it. This might work out for very small reads, but you're doing a minimum of 100bytes, and you should never rely on it in any case.

### With respect to the file-descriptor?

pread() may be used by multiple threads at once on the same file-descriptor. I think that may be why it was designed. Of course, each thread will need its own buffer to hold the data.

### With respect to the disk?

O_SYNC isn't terribly useful for reads. When used with writes, O_SYNC means that at the end of a call, the data in your buffer is now flushed. That might mean it exists on the disk, or it might mean it has been flushed over a connection. For reads, you may need to use O_RSYNC. O_RSYNC will force reading calls to block until any needed metadata updates are complete. An example of this would be filesystems with recorded 'access time'.